# QML Update Gridview from QML or C++ without emit dataChanged

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QAbstractListModel, which is tied to QML via

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty
```

which is displayed in a GridView. It contains cards like Aces, Queens etc. I would like to sort the cards in different ways (like color, type etc). The sorting fuction can be called via qml:

```
GridView
{
    id:table_player
    model: Playerfield
    delegate: Card
    {
        card_id: model.card_id
        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            Playerfield.sortDeck()
        }
    }
}
```

The C++ Code:

```
public slots:
    Q_INVOKABLE void sortDeck();
```

It works, but only updates the Playfield, when a card is changed / a new card is played. I need a way to send a signal other than "emit dataChanged()" to QML to update. Or a way directly from QML to Update the Gridview with the changed model data (table_player.update() does not work).

```
void Deckmodel::sortDeck()
{
    for(uint a = 0; a < cards.size(); a++)
    {
        for(uint b = a+1; b < cards.size(); b++)
        {
            if(cards[a].type > cards[b].type)
            {
                Card temp = cards[a];
                cards[a] = cards[b];
                cards[b] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
//insert signal here
}
```

Comment: emit QAbstractListModel::layoutChanged();
seems to work, but take care not to trigger an infinity call loop, but reacting to redrawn with sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Deckmodel` the same thing as `Playerfield` in your code? When changing your model, you need to call begin/endResetModel(). That will automatically emit the appropriate signals so your QML should update correclty.

```
void Deckmodel::sortDeck()
{
    beginResetModel();

    for(uint a = 0; a < cards.size(); a++)
    {
        for(uint b = a+1; b < cards.size(); b++)
        {
            if(cards[a].type > cards[b].type)
            {
                Card temp = cards[a];
                cards[a] = cards[b];
                cards[b] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    endResetModel();
}
```

Comment: I used layoutAboutToBeChanged now and it works, but beginResetModel seems to be the correct solution.

void Deckmodel::sortDeck()
{
 emit layoutAboutToBeChanged();
//sort
}

void Deckmodel::sortDeckIncludingLayoutSignal()
{
 sortDeck();
 emit layoutChanged();
}